# Why is OWIN's SignInAsync() not setting IsAuthenticated (or other authentication variables)?

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-identity, owin

I have a .NET, MVC 5, EF 6 project.  We're connecting to an external project/database for authenticating users, so all we need to implement is login and logout methods, not normal CRUD methods.  I know I have EF mapped correctly to the external database's tables; I can see it get the users.

I'm trying to use OWIN to authenticate so that I can use attributes like `[Authorize]` throughout the controller methods.  I've been following [this](http://www.aspenrootsdevelopment.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity2.0-Custom-Database/) as my guide.

In Startup.Auth.cs I have:

```
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<CustomUserManager>(CustomUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<CustomSignInManager>(CustomSignInManager.Create);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)
            )
        },
        CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always
    });
```

I also have classes implementing interfaces `IUserStore<User>`, `UserManager<User>`, and `SignInManager<User, string>`.  My `CustomUserStore` has the following method implemented because the source says that's how it does logins.  I implemented dummy methods for the other functions (i.e. `DeleteAsync()`, `UpdateAsync()`, etc.) that don't need to be implemented because we have read-only access to this external users db...

```
    public async Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        using (ExternalDBContext context = new ExternalDBContext())
        {
            return await Task.Run(() =>
                context.Users.Where(u => u.Id == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault()
            );
        }
    }
```

Then in my AccountController.Login() I have:

```
        await CustomSignInManager.SignInAsync(model, true, true);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
```

But after `SignInAsync()`, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is still `false` and therefore none of the authorize attributes won't work.

**#1 Possible Problem:**  I'm wondering if the problem is with `AuthenticationManager`, which `SignInManager` relies on.  Here's how I'm implementing it in Startup.Auth.cs:

```
public class CustomSignInManager : SignInManager<User, string>
{
    public CustomSignInManager(CustomUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }
    public static CustomSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<CustomSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new CustomSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<CustomUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

It gets a `Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager` from the context.

So: do I need to do something else to implement authentication?

**#2 Possible Problem:** I notice my `CustomUserManager` has a property `SupportsUserLogin = false`.  [That property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613199%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) requires implementing [IUserLoginStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613272%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).  I don't want to implement yet another useless interface full of methods that I'm not using!

So: does it matter if `SupportsUserLogin = false`?  Do I need to implement that interface or is there a way around this?

**Summary:** Overall this has gotten too complicated for a project where all I want to do is LOG THE USER IN.  And out.  I don't want to create/update/delete users.  I just want to log a user in and have `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = true` until they logout.  So any ideas about how to backtrack to a simpler way of using Identity framework would be most greatly appreciated.  My biggest question is whether I'm going down the right route at all.

**Edit:**
I definitely don't want to do #2 (implement IUserLoginStore) [because that is for doing external authentication](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity).

Comment: If you generate a project from a template it essentially gets you there. You attempting a DB-first approach or customized tables? If that's the case you have definitely gone too far and a simpler way exists.

Comment: Code-first, not db-first.  If what's the case I've gone too far?

Comment: Can you try adding this to your signinmanager? public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(User user){ return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((UserManager)UserManager);}

Comment: I don't have a GenerateUserIdentityAsync() method defined for my User class.  Do I need to write one, and if so, can you post/link to an example?

Comment: Yes, here you go... public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User, int> manager) { var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie); return userIdentity; }

Comment: @Shoe actually he already should have it as it says:
regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)
and that won't fix his issue.

Comment: @pajics That is for regenerating an identity. That doesn't set one up on sign in.

Comment: I agree, but he (not you :) ) said that he doesn't have that method  and he must have it as it is used in startup...

Comment: @Shoe I added the method to User.  Then instantiated userManager in the CustomSignInManager constructor and assigned it with `this.userManager = userManager;`.  Got the solution to compile, but still have the same problem: after calling `await CustomSignInManager.SignInAsync(model, true, true);`, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;` is still false.

Comment: Also: I noticed that after calling `SignInAsync()`, `User.Identity.AuthenticationType` is empty.  Am I missing a step?

Comment: Can you verify your identity object is being setup correctly via this code? `var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);`

Comment: For anyone curious who stumbles across this, I ended up having to abandon trying to get OWIN authentication to work correctly; I just home-spun the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

are you using https?
if not remove this line: CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always

also there is no need for IUserLoginStore (that is only for external auth like facebook)
more info about that: [here](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity)

side note:
change Task.Factory.StartNew to Task.Run [link](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

Comment: Yes I'm using https, it needs to be secure obviously.  Thanks for the note on IUserLoginStore.